# Piping file via commandline with C#?

Tags: java, c#

in Java I'm able to do the following in the commandline:

```
javac MyClass.java
java MyClass < SomeFile.txt
```

That will pipe the contents of `SomeFile.txt` into the input stream for MyClass to read with some kind of `Scanner` or `BufferedReader`.

How could I do the same thing in C#? I know there is a commandline arguments section in "Project" in Visual Studio, but simply adding `< SomeFile.txt` did nothing. It read the `<` as an argument and couldn't interpret it.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput.

Answer (score 0):

You use a greater than symbol > to record the Standard out, and >2 to record the error output

In your example, you're showing a less than symbol (<), which reads in an input file instead of using the keyboard.

Here is the Microsoft TechNet article that explains the usage:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx

Comment: Yeah, in your link < provides me with what I need:"Reads the command input from a file, instead of reading input from the keyboard."

What I'm wondering is how to do this with C# since it isn't something you typically compile/run directly from the commandline.